# Column name overlaps with type column in Data Explorer in PendingFlags table

Tags: bug, data-explorer

In the SE Data Explorer, if you attempt to compose a query and scroll to the `PendingFlags` table, two columns (`CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId` and `BelongsOnBaseHostAddress`) overlap into the column type column:

[image: Bug Picture of columns]

I was able to see this in both Chrome and IE.

Comment: Tbh I'd rather have that overlap happen than something like ellipses, at least you can copy+paste the column name this way.

Comment: @JasonC even with elipsis you can copy the whole field. (assuming you leave to overflow handling to the browser